# Flutter - Mockito - Using async in testing produces an error but using async* made it work fine?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, asynchronous, dart-null-safety

In short, I'm following the ResoCoder TDD Course. The course is a bit outdated but I'm pretty sure it's fine to follow along and make adjustments along the way. The course and the code in GitHub for this course is not null-safety.

And I'm not following the course exactly. I made a few changes here and there.

I'm just into the course at about episode 2 or 3 for context.

*auth_usecases_test.dart*

```
import 'package:dartz/dartz.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';
import 'package:storayge/core/auth/domain/entities/local_user.dart';
import 'package:storayge/core/auth/domain/repository/auth_repository.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:storayge/core/auth/domain/usecases/auth_usecases.dart';

class MockAuthRepository extends Mock implements AuthRepository {}

void main() {
  late GetLocalUserDataFromRemote usecase;
  late MockAuthRepository mockAuthRepository;

  late String tUid;
  late LocalUser tLocalUser;

  setUp(() {
    mockAuthRepository = MockAuthRepository();
    usecase = GetLocalUserDataFromRemote(repository: mockAuthRepository);
    tLocalUser = const LocalUser(
      username: 'testUsername',
      email: 'testEmail@Email',
      uid: 'testUid',
    );
    tUid = 'testUid';
  });

  test(
    'should get LocalUser data from the repository',
    () async* {
      // arrange
      when(mockAuthRepository.getLocalUserDataFromRemote(uid: tUid))
          .thenAnswer((_) async => Right(tLocalUser));
      // act
      final result = await usecase(Params(uid: tUid));
      // assert
      expect(result, equals(Right(tLocalUser)));
      verify(mockAuthRepository.getLocalUserDataFromRemote(uid: tUid));
      verifyNoMoreInteractions(mockAuthRepository);
    },
  );
}
```

This is the "working" code. If I change the `async*` keyword to just `async` it produces this error:

```
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Either<Failure, LocalUser>>'
```

*auth_usecases.dart*

```
class GetLocalUserDataFromRemote implements Usecase<LocalUser, Params> {
  final AuthRepository repository;

  GetLocalUserDataFromRemote({required this.repository});

  @override
  Future<Either<Failure, LocalUser>> call(Params params) async {
    return repository.getLocalUserDataFromRemote(uid: params.uid);
  }
}

class Params extends Equatable {
  final String uid;

  Params({required this.uid});

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [uid];
}
```

*auth_repository.dart*

```
import 'package:dartz/dartz.dart';

import '../../../errors/failures.dart';
import '../entities/local_user.dart';

abstract class AuthRepository {
  Future<Either<Failure, LocalUser>> getLocalUserDataFromRemote({
    required String uid,
  });

  Future<Either<Failure, LocalUser>> signInWithEmailAndPassword({
    required String email,
    required String password,
  });
}
```

*local_user.dart*

```
class LocalUser extends Equatable {
  final String username;
  final String email;
  final String uid;

  const LocalUser({
    required this.username,
    required this.email,
    required this.uid,
  });

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [username, email, uid];
}
```

*failures.dart*

```
abstract class Failure extends Equatable {
  final List<Object> properties;

  const Failure({required this.properties});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => properties;
}
```

Why and how does changing the async tag make it work? I'm stumped.

Edit: My packages are all currently latest with sound null safety. Except dartz which im using 0.1.0-nullsafety.1

Edit 2: Some updates. First of all it seems like using the async* tag makes the test pass, BUT it does not seem to actually work. I mean the testing passes even when it should have not. I think I have found the solution. And its of course my fault. The mockito docs says that the mockito does support null safety, BUT with some code generation. With the custom mock classes and whatnot. I didnt do any, which is dumb and I hate myself. So ima do some of that and update it later on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay. I finally found the answer. And yes, it's my own dumb fault.
Basically mockito 5.0.0 does support null safety now, with some caveats. You will need to generate mock classes using some code generation. Which I did not. basically what I did is

```
class MockAuthRepository extends Mock implements AuthRepository {} // remove

@GenerateMocks([AuthRepository]) //new
void main() {
  late GetLocalUserDataFromRemote usecase;
  late MockAuthRepository mockAuthRepository;

  late String tUid;
  late LocalUser tLocalUser;

  setUp(() {
    mockAuthRepository = MockAuthRepository();
    usecase = GetLocalUserDataFromRemote(repository: mockAuthRepository);
    tLocalUser = const LocalUser(
      username: 'testUsername',
      email: 'testEmail@Email',
      uid: 'testUid',
    );
    tUid = 'testUid';
  });

  test(
    'should get LocalUser data from the repository',
    () async {
      // arrange
      when(mockAuthRepository.getLocalUserDataFromRemote(anyNamed('uid')))
          .thenAnswer((_) async => Right(tLocalUser));
      // act
      final result = await usecase(Params(uid: tUid));
      // assert
      expect(result, equals(Right(tLocalUser)));
      verify(mockAuthRepository.getLocalUserDataFromRemote(uid: tUid));
      verifyNoMoreInteractions(mockAuthRepository);
    },
  );
}
```

And generate it with build runner. It's pretty easy. I'm just that dumb and didnt read the docs carefully.

Comment: don't feel bad. i just wasted two hours for skipping over the generate. end of day, so i will resolve tomorrow. sadly, while learning flutter, i ran into this very thing and did the generate. ahhhh!

Comment: thank you, I did the same mistake, you saved me.

Comment: Thank you. Same situation here. Following the Resocoder TDD course and haven't thought that dependencies also were affected by null-safety and just adapted the Dart part of the code.. Thanks for pointing it out. Yo saved me too.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a mockito failure.

Try calling your code this way as the [mockito docs](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito) state:

```
      // arrange
      when(mockAuthRepository.getLocalUserDataFromRemote(uid: anyNamed('uid')))
          .thenAnswer((_) async => Right(tLocalUser));
```

Comment: I tried this. The problem persists. I did need to change the uid type to dynamic. Same thing, async* works. async gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

I think this works as streams worked for BLoC. You have the async* in the `mapEventToState` function and you can more async after that

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).